# ASP.NET Edit and Delete issues in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have created GridView with Insert, Edit, and Delete function. The Insert work great but not Delete and Edit. When I click Delete, it suppose to be automatic delete row but it never happen because it still there. Second issue same for Edit, I click Edit, then I change something there then click update, nothing changed after clicked and there data still the same in GridView. I am sure I am missing tiny things... Please help!

Here the C# code behind HTML,

```
protected void GridViewServer_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewServer.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindGridView();          

    }

    protected void GridViewServer_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewServer.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGridView();           
    }

    protected void GridViewServer_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {           
        GridViewRow _row = GridViewServer.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Label servername = (Label)_row.FindControl("lblServerName");

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from tblServer where ServerName = '" + servername + "'", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        GridViewServer.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGridView();
        conn.Close();

    }

    protected void GridViewServer_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {


        GridViewRow _row = GridViewServer.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Label servername = (Label)_row.FindControl("lblServerName");
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblServer set ClusterName = @ClusterName, Architecture = @Architecture, Database_Type = @DataType, Restriction = @Restriction, Business_Continuity_Plan = @BCP, Tenant_Code = @TenantCode where ClusterName =  '" + servername + "'", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServerName", ((Label)_row.FindControl("lblServerName")).Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClusterName", ((DropDownList)_row.FindControl("DropDownClusterName")).Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Architecture", ((DropDownList)_row.FindControl("DropDownArchitecture")).Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataType", ((DropDownList)_row.FindControl("DropDownDataType")).Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Restriction", ((DropDownList)_row.FindControl("DropDownRestriction")).Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BCP", ((TextBox)_row.FindControl("txtBCP")).Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TenantCode", ((TextBox)_row.FindControl("txtTenantCode")).Text);

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        GridViewServer.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGridView();
        conn.Close();

    }
```

and

```
public void BindGridView()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();

        string sqlquery = ("SELECT * FROM tblServer");

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adp.Fill(ds);

        GridViewServer.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        GridViewServer.DataBind();
    }
```

The GridView HTML code if you need to see,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewServer" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="ServerName" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" onrowcancelingedit="GridViewServer_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowdeleting="GridViewServer_RowDeleting" onrowediting="GridViewServer_RowEditing" 
        onrowupdating="GridViewServer_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>               
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ServerName" SortExpression="ServerName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblServerName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ServerName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="txtServerName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ServerName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtServerName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvServerName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtServerName" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ClusterName" SortExpression="ClusterName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblClusterName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClusterName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownClusterName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="ClusterName" DataTextField="ClusterName" DataValueField="ClusterName">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownClusterName" runat="server" DataSourceID="ClusterName" DataTextField="ClusterName" DataValueField="ClusterName">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ClusterName" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ClusterName] FROM [tblCluster]"></asp:SqlDataSource>                       
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Architecture" SortExpression="Architecture">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblArchitecture" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Architecture") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownArchitecture" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSN EAP</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSN NEA</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSNConnect.com</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSNDMZ.COM</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dow EAP</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dow NEA</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownArchitecture" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSN EAP</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSN NEA</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSNConnect.com</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSNDMZ.COM</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dow EAP</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dow NEA</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvArchitecture" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownArchitecture" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Database_Type" SortExpression="Database_Type">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDatabaseType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Database_Type") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownDataType" runat="server" >
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Oracle</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownDataType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Oracle</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDatabaseType" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownDataType" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Life_Cycle_Stage" SortExpression="Life_Cycle_Stage">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLCS" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Life_Cycle_Stage") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownLCS" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dev</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Prod</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Test</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownLCS" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dev</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Prod</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Test</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLCS" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownLCS" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Restriction" SortExpression="Restriction">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRestriction" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Restriction") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownRestriction" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Export Controlled</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SOX Critical</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Standard</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownRestriction" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Export Controlled</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SOX Critical</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Standard</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRestriction" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownRestriction" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Business_Continuity_Plan" SortExpression="Business_Continuity_Plan">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblBCP" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Business_Continuity_Plan") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBCP" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Business_Continuity_Plan") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtBCP" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvBCP" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBCP" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tenant_Code" SortExpression="Tenant_Code">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTenantCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Tenant_Code") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTenantCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Tenant_Code") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtTenantCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTenantCode" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTenantCode" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" CausesValidation="false" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" SortExpression="Insert">                  
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkInsert" runat="server" Text ="Insert" OnClick="lnkInsert_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all..? first of all when you are connecting to the Database as well as where you are executing the query, I would suggest wrapping your code around a using as well as a try {}catch{} also report back if you are getting any errors or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `Label` instead of the `Label.Text` Property.

So you are Editing/Deleting 0 rows.
Code should be:

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from tblServer where ServerName = '" + servername.Text + "'", conn);
```

And

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblServer set ClusterName = @ClusterName, Architecture = @Architecture, Database_Type = @DataType, Restriction = @Restriction, Business_Continuity_Plan = @BCP, Tenant_Code = @TenantCode where ClusterName =  '" + servername.Text + "'", conn);
```

Notice the `servername.Text` that was modified.

Comment: I'm surprised it is compiling...I think it must be using "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label" in the WHERE clause (and I doubt you have a server named adter that).

Comment: I fix from what you mentions above. The delete part worked but the Edit part still issue. I did change servername.Text and also fix the WHERE clause from ClusterName to ServerName. The error result says, "NullReferenceException", Object reference not set to an instance of an object on sername.Text in update query.

Comment: You're looking for "lblServerName" in the RowUpdating method but I think that should be "txtServerName" since the EditItemTemplate has a textbox with that name but no label.